# Unable to get Mongoose Model.findOneAndDelete to work

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongodb document in mongoose that contains a nested object.

I wish to delete the document, so I initiated a query against the document as follows

```
    await MyDocument.findOneAndDelete({ 'nestedObject._id': target._id }); //This doesn't work
```

But, unfortunately the delete is not working as the document is still in the database

Surprisingly if I try to retrieve the document using:

```
let doc = await MyDocument.findOne({ 'nestedObject._id': target._id }); //This is successfully retrieving the document.
```

So, it's a bit surprising that delete is not working but find is working.

I'm using `mongoose version 5.13.3`

What can I do differently to get this working?
Thanks

Comment: What is returned from findOneAndDelete?

Comment: Thats strange. Maybe the target._id is not in ObjectID format? You can also try remove() or deleteOne().

Comment: @Joe The deleted document was actually returned, but the document is still in the database.